# How do I get an element from other array using current context's @key in Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, templating-engine

I have these two contexts:

```
dow = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

businessHours = {
    days: [
        ["08:00", "22:00"],
        ["08:00", "22:00"],
        ["08:00", "22:00"],
        false,
        ["08:00", "22:00"],
        false,
        false
    ],
    openOnHolidays: false
}
```

Now I'm trying to render each of `businessHours.days` into a table with each row containing the day's name from `dow` in one cell and the hours in the other. I tried doing it like this

```
{{#hours}}
<table>{{#each days}}
<tr>
    <td>{{@root.dow.[@key]}}</td> <!-- This is the line I'm talking about ->
    <td>{{#if this}}{{this.[0]}} - {{this.[1]}}{{/if}}{{#unless this}}Closed{{/unless}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}</table>
{{#unless openOnHolidays}}Closed on holidays{{/unless}}
{{/hours}}
```

But it doesn't render the day's name. I'm not converting `businessHours.days` into a plain object because an object's properties are not stored in fixed order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved using [Handlebar's `lookup` helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup).

```js
{{lookup @root.dow @key}}
```

See working snippet below.

```js
var data = {
  dow: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
  hours: {
    days: [
      ["08:00", "22:00"],
      ["08:00", "22:00"],
      ["08:00", "22:00"],
      false,
      ["08:00", "22:00"],
      false,
      false
    ],
    openOnHolidays: false
  }
};

var source = $('#entry-template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source)(data);

$('body').html(template)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#hours}}
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Hours</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each days}}
<tr>
    <td>{{lookup @root.dow @key}}</td>
    <td>{{#if this}}{{this.[0]}} - {{this.[1]}}{{/if}}{{#unless this}}Closed{{/unless}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
{{#unless openOnHolidays}}Closed on holidays{{/unless}}
{{/hours}}
</script>
```